# angular2 set active tab on init

Tags: angular

I am trying to set active class on a tab in angular2. I am using the ng2-bootstrap plugin for tabs and really do not unterstand how to do it.

From original examples of ng2-bootstrap:

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Static title">Static content</tab>
    <tab *ngFor="let tabz of tabs"
         [heading]="tabz.title"
         [active]="tabz.active"
         (select)="tabz.active = true"
         (deselect)="tabz.active = false"
         [disabled]="tabz.disabled"
         [removable]="tabz.removable"
         (removed)="removeTabHandler(tabz)">
      {{tabz?.content}}
    </tab>
    <tab (select)="alertMe()">
      <template tabHeading>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
      </template>
      I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
    </tab>
  </tabset>
```

So if I want to set the last tab as active on load, how can I access this tab in typescript? The main problem is that I can only acces the tabs which are created in typescript itself, but not the static tabs like the first or the last one.

I like to achieve something like:

```
ngOnActivate() {
    tab[4].activ=true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At first, i understood you wrong, so i updated my answer.
To get the static tabs in your example, you have to set an id to them like this:

```
<tabset>
    <tab #headingTab heading="Static title">Static content</tab>
     ...
```

Then using `@ViewChild` you can get a hold of the `ElementRef` which has a property `nativeElement` which is probaby what you want.

In your Component you have to import `TabsetComponent` from ng2-bootstrap:

```
...
import {TAB_DIRECTIVES, TabsetComponent} from "ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap";
...
```

To access it you have to hook into the `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook, so you have to import `AfterViewInit` and implement it like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('headingTab')       // id of the tab in your html template
    private _headingTab:TabsetComponent;  // followed by a variable which will hold the component

     ngAfterViewInit():any {
         console.log(this._headingTab);
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact I need access to all of the tabs. In my example I only use static tabs and I want a url parameter to control which tab will be active.
So I think i will add an id to every tab and then will try to access with ViewChildren.

Answer (score 3):

In my Angular 5 app using ngx-bootstrap TabsControl, I have static tabs and need to set the active tab based on the results of an observable call, which is made in the ngOnInit function.  For me, my code is doing the following:

first get the entire tabset into ngx-bootstrap's TabsetComponent:

```
@ViewChild(TabsetComponent)
tabSet: TabsetComponent;
```

Then in the success action of the observable's subscription (when I'll know the tab to choose):

```
if (showMessageTab) {
    this.tabSet.tabs[4].active = true;
} else {
    this.tabSet.tabs[0].active = true;
}
```

Another thing I ran into is that the  and the  items cannot be late loaded using ngIf or other angular properties.  In my experiments, in order for angular to  populate the ViewChild element, it appears they have to be in the html from the first load.  That's probably obvious to you already, but I throw it in as I ran into it.

I hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<tab (select)="alertMe()" [ngClass]="{active: last}">
      <template tabHeading>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
      </template>
      I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
 </tab>
```

Comment: you were 4 seconds faster ;) but you've got some errors in your code. `this.tabs..` and you probably want the key to be dynamic if you explicitly want the last one.

Comment: But you both didn't read the question carefully, this is not what OP's is asking.

Comment: true, i updated my answer as well. thanks for the hint dfsq ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this in the template

```
<tabset>
  <tab [active]="currentTabId === 0">Tab1 Content<tab>
  <tab [active]="currentTabId === 1">Tab2 Content<tab>
  <tab [active]="currentTabId === 2">Tab3 Content<tab>
</tabset>
```

And in the typescript, add

```
currentTabId = 1
```

Comment: It looks that he is trying to reuse html tab declaration for a list of tabs. Your solution would be ok for different implementations.